# HiveQL how logic filter statement treats NULL values

Tags: sql, hive, hql, hiveql

I have a sample dataset such as following:

```
Id  Name            ReferredBy
1   John Doe        NULL
2   Jane Smith      NULL
3   Anne Jenkins        2
4   Eric Branford       NULL
5   Pat Richards        1
6   Alice Barnes        2
```

If I want to select all recorded not referred by Jane Smith I would use the following command:

```
SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE ReferredBy <> 2;
```

On SQL Server, this will exclude NULL values so I need to write it in the following way:

```
SELECT Name FROM Customers WHERE ReferredBy IS NULL OR ReferredBy <> 2
```

Does HiveQL have the same issue?

*It is hard to test it out on the raw dataset I have since it is quiet large with very few missings.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not an issue.  This is how `NULL` values are defined in SQL and how all databases behave.

Comment: So the first statement will give the desired output?

Comment: . . Presumably, the second is the one that you want.  That is basically what is needed in any database, although some databases have support for `NULL`-safe operators, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of `NULL` is defined by SQL and all databases respect it.  That said, the standard also specifies `NULL` safe comparison operators, `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` and `IS DISTINCT FROM`.  Hive supports one for equality, but not that one.

For your logic, you can use this Hive extension for [`<=>`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-LogicalOperators):

```
where not (ReferredBy <=> 2)
```

The `<=>` is the `NULL`-safe comparison, so it returns "true" for `NULL <=> NULL` and "false" for `NULL <=> 2`, instead of `NULL` in both cases.  This is presumably borrowed from MySQL.